# C programming read multiple lines and pause until pressing any key from keyboard

Tags: c

I am very new in C programming. I hope I can explain my problem. I am trying to develop a program to read a `binary` file and convert to `ASCII` mode. There was no any problem for this. But what I have to do is ask user ones, how many lines he/she wants to read(for example 20 lines) then only show 20 lines from binary file and ask user press any key to continue. After pressing any key then again show next 20 lines from that file and so on.

I tried to use `getch()` and `getchar()` but that worked only for one line.

My following code may help to explain properly. Please help me out from this. Thank you in advance.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void header(); //Title function declaration

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp; // File pointer declaration
    int i, j;
    unsigned char buffer[17]; // Trying to get value for 16 bites each

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); 
    if (argc == 1) { // Condition for if user didnt specify file name
        /* Assume that argv[0] is the program name */
        printf("usage: %s, <file_name>", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    if (fp == NULL) { // condition if there is no file 
        fprintf(stderr, "File Open error (%s) , error = %d", argv[1], errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
        header(); // Calling function header

        int read = 0;
        int address = 0;
        while ((read = fread(buffer, 1, 16, fp)) > 0)
        {
            printf("%08X", address); 
            printf(" ");
            address += 16;

            for (i = 0; i < read; i++)
            {
                if (i == 8) {
                    if (buffer[i] != NULL)
                        printf("-");
                }
                else {

                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("%02X", buffer[i]);
            }

            int space = 16 - read;

            if (space != 0) {

                for (int x = 0; x < space; x++) {
                    int y = read + (x - buffer[x]);
                    printf("   ");
                }
            }
            printf("  ");
            for (j = 0; j < read; j++)
            {
                if (buffer[j] == NULL) {
                    printf(".");
                }
                if (isprint(buffer[j])) {
                    printf("%c", buffer[j]);
                    //fflush(stdin);
                }
                else {
                    if (buffer[j] != NULL) {
                        printf(".");
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n");

        }

    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void header() {
    printf("ADDRESS  ");

    for (int i = 0X00; i <= 0X0F; i++)
    {
        if (i == 8) {
            printf("-");
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%02X", i);
    }
    printf("  0123456789ABCDEF \n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

}
```

> And output should be like
>   [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpAgg.png)

Comment: help me understand what you want to get, after each iteration you want to ask the user if he wants to continue and then repeat this procudre?

Comment: @YoniNewman Thank you for your comment. No only one time ask user. then read same number of lines till end after pressing some key from keyboard

Comment: C doesn't deal with keys. There are third party libraries that do, but they could be a bit daunting to use. I would recommend a more beginner friendly solution. Ask the user to press Enter, rather than  "any key". Then you can use `fgets` to read the resulting line.

Comment: so the problem is that your program prints only 1 line per iteration instead of the number that the user asked?

Comment: `"read a binary file and convert to ASCII mode"` -- you know in a binary file there is no concept of a "line". You would have to read a number of bytes from the file into a buffer and scan through the buffer looking for the `'\n'` character (ASCII `10`, `0xa` (hex)).

Comment: @YoniNewman yes exactly but i need to print output as user defined lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your reading and printing logic inside loops.

```
int read = 0;
int address = 0;
int numLines = 0;

printf("How many lines you want to print?");
scanf("%d", &numLines);
do {

       for(int i = 0; i<numLines; i++)
       {
                if ((read = fread(buffer, 1, 16, fp)) > 0)
                {
                      ....... //your printing logic here
                }
       }

       /*Flush input stream in case \n left out*/
       int c;
       while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }

       printf("press Any key to continue\n");
       getchar();
 } while(read>0);
```

Comment: Birdar Thank you for your solution and I tried with your sample code but with this code read all lines and at a time and at last ask press any key to continue then terminate the program..

Comment: The question, to a large extent is about `"....... //your printing logic here"`. How do you propose doing that?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It will remain same as it is proposed in the question. I thought of reading `numLines` at once but OP printing logic will have to change.

Comment: getch() is not what you write nowadays, are you using some ancient compiler?

Comment: @Niksankarkee Is it waiting for key press?

Comment: @ kiran Birdar yes it is waiting for key press but after printing all lines from binary file and after  pressing the key all progrem is terminates

Comment: @Niksankarkee It is because `read` is becoming `-1`, are you sure there are more lines in the file?

Comment: @Niksankarkee My mistake `while` should be `if` -->`if ((read = fread(buffer, 1, 16, fp)) > 0) `

Comment: @kiran Biradar yes there is around 20 lines and i put the value in numLines variable only 2... program print all 20 lines then ask to press any key

Comment: @Niksankarkee I have updated the answer, please check now.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I changed while to if now printing only one line each whatever the value i put into the nulLines variable only one line is printing. ank ask for press any key to continue. Everytime prints only 1 line.

Comment: Are you sure you are including the for loop?

Comment: @kiranBiradar Yes I copied from your Answer

Comment: @Niksankarkee can you post your tried code in the question?

Comment: @kiranBiradar I mistake i used same variable two times for different use. Now its working. Thank you so much